# Azure Key vault Certificate based Authentication - Production Deployment

Tags: azure-keyvault

- Using a self-signed certificate is only recommended for development, not production.

What certificate should a team buy when Application moves to Production - TIA

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, certificates are bought from the [certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) for production scenarios.

> a **certificate authority** or **certification authority** (**CA**) is
> an entity that issues [digital
> certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate). A digital certificate certifies the
> ownership of a public key by the named subject of the certificate.
> This allows others (relying parties) to rely upon signatures or on
> assertions made about the private key that corresponds to the
> certified public key. A CA acts as a trusted third party—trusted both
> by the subject (owner) of the certificate and by the party relying
> upon the certificate. The format of these certificates is specified by
> the [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) or
> [EMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV) standard.

Reference: https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/06/20/service-principal-and-certificate-with-azure-key-vault/

Comment: You cannot blindly use a certificate purchased from a CA.

I have a console app which works great with self signed and if I try it against CA certificate code fails.